# How to Enable the Saturday & Sunday in DayPilot Pro 7.1.2741

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, timetable, daypilot

I'm using DayPilot Pro 7.1.2741 Trial, and will shows only Monday to Friday. 
I want it to show saturday and sunday alwell

Link for DayPilot Pro 7.1.2741

http://code.daypilot.org/65101/timetable-tutorial-asp-net-c-vb-net

http://www.daypilot.org/tutorial/timetable/

So please help with enabling these days.

Comment: what is problem? http://code.daypilot.org/65101/timetable-tutorial-asp-net-c-vb-net is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set DayPilotCalendar.Days to 7. Page_Load method in Default.aspx.cs should look like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    blocks = new DataManager().GetBlocks();

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate = Week.FirstWorkingDayOfWeek(DayPilotNavigator1.SelectionStart);
        DayPilotCalendar1.Days = 7; 

        DayPilotCalendar1.DataSource = new DataManager().GetAssignments(DayPilotCalendar1);
        DayPilotCalendar1.DataBind();
    }
}
```